# Materialize Grid for irregular boxes not workings

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am trying to make the front end using materialize and I have used Django for the backend. The current look I am getting is something like this:

[image]

And I want it to be more like this:

[image]

I am using Django and Materialize. And [here](https://codeshare.io/amA4oX) is the code I have written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This layout is easy to achieve with [CSS grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout), but if you wanted to approximate it with the Materialize grid, you just need to fix your columns and use a bit of flex.

The example you want to replicate has two main columns:

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- Two columns, wider on the left -->
    <div class="col s12 l8">Left</div>
    <div class="col s12 l4">Right</div>
</div>
```

The left hand column than has nested rows and columns, like this:

```
<div class="row">
      <!-- Three columns -->
      <div class="col s4"></div>
      <div class="col s4"></div>
      <div class="col s4"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
      <!-- One column -->
      <div class="col s12"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
      <!-- Three columns -->
      <div class="col s4"></div>
      <div class="col s4"></div>
      <div class="col s4"></div>
</div>
```

We need to use [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) on two of the rows - this forces the content to stretch to fit. Be careful with flex, it breaks the grid system at small screen sizes.

We also need a bit of css to force the button to fill the container, and to remove the margin bottom from the last row. I've created a wrapper called `.content` that we'll use to apply the padding (same as the margin from the rows for consistency).

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/abpoJOP).

Comment: OMG, thank you so much. Thank you for your time and effort, I really appreciate it! I really do, you are an awesome human! You don't know how much this means to me!